# node.js & Express fs.rename random Error: EPERM, operation not permitted ! how to fix it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

i got a problem with the fs.rename function! Sometimes it doesn´t works and i don´t know why. I try to upload some files and rename it! So it should be work for a time.
in the codes below:

```
exports.up = function(req, res){
        var len = [].concat(req.files.fileSelect);
            for(var i = 0; i < len.length; i++) {
                var tmp_path =(len[i].path);
                if(len[i].name ==''){
                len[i].name ='empty';

                }
                    console.log(len[i]);
                    var target_path =('./public/images/' + len[i].name);
                    fs.rename(tmp_path, target_path, function(err) {
                        if (err) throw err;
                        fs.unlink(tmp_path, function() {
                            if (err) throw err;
                        });
                    });
            }   
            res.redirect('/picture');
    };
```

Comment: Have you checked the permissions on that directory?